# What table structure is better for categories and custom user categories

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a categories and users table. A user can have many categories and a category can have many users (many to many). However, I also need a feature were users can insert/create their own categories and which is only accessible to the user (category creator) + the defaults categories.

I created a pivot table to handle the many to many relationship, however, I was having difficulty deciding if I need to create another table to handle the custom user categories or just add a user_id on the categories table.

What would be the correct structure I should take/create to handle this.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're asking for "the best", you're expected to have evaluated your choices and present the remaining ones. Or are you just looking for someone to design the structure for you?

Comment: Wel, sorry for not adding more information..I created a pivot table to handle the many to many relationship, however, I was having difficulty deciding if I need to create another table to handle the custom user categories or just add a user_id on the categories table..so maybe thats why I ask for the best approach..I might used the wrong word..apologies ..do you have any suggestions on which correct path I should take @CodeCaster? thanks

Comment: There are different ways to solve this, all of which depend on the database design and intended use. Please [edit] your question to show that additional information. :)

Comment: Updated, hope that clears things..do you have a suggestion on those ways to solve this? I would love to try it out. thanks. I only need default categories ,users and custom categories created by the user which will be associated to the user.

Comment: An easy fix would be to add a UserId with the relation, and show all records where that field is `null` or contains the Id of the user requesting it, but whether that's viable really depends on the rest of the logic.

Comment: There's still not enough information here I'm afraid. When you say users can have many categories, but there are defaults, how are the defaults getting inserted, and why are they a part of the many-to-many relationship if they are "default"?

Comment: (also, don't forget to @ tag people in your responses so that they recieve emails when you answer their queries ;) )

Comment: I see..so my second approach is ok to add the user_id into the categories table and just make the default user_id = 0 and let the code handle the rest...I was hesitant to do this as I was thinking I might taking the wrong path and there is much better approach to handle it. Thanks for the help @CodeCaster

Comment: @PhilipAdler - thanks for the comment - 

categories table will have like - teacher, carpenter etc.. and a user can have many categories and categories can have many users..however, if in any case a category is not available on the default list of categories..a user is able to add new categories but should only be associated to that user and will not be available to the other users.

Comment: Yes, I'd have a table of user added categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information you have described, there are two solutions which would be valid: one would be to have a separate table for custom categories, and my preferred solution, would be to have a boolean value on the categories table which indicates whether a category is custom or not. This gives you the following advantages:

- Logic applied to the two similar kinds of category remains the same
- Other fields which are shared can be kept, in kind
- If you wish to convert a custom category to a real category, this then becomes trivial (change the boolean)

You could include a creator id field to identify the person to whom the category applies, alternatively, you might simply designate in-code that custom categories may only have one member.

Comment: Thank you @PhilipAdler for taking time to answer..I will try this approach.